# Launch Daemon to keep me logged out between certain times

Tags: launchd, plist

I'm currently trying to figure out how to better control the time I spend on my laptop in the evenings, but for reasons I'll spare you, I'm not having a lot of success. I'm finding that the OSx parental controls aren't much good, as all they require (as of Catalina) is a 4 digit code. There's no 4 digit code I could set that I won't immediately remember. It used to be the case that you could set any password you wanted for use with parental controls, and I used to have a password that was generated out of 20+ pages of a book. So that I could get back into my laptop if I absolutely needed to, but generating the password was a long and laborious endeavour.

I've been trying to see if running one or more Launch Daemons might be a better solution.

I currently have the following Daemon running:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<!-- SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0 -->
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>local.lock-session-bedtime</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession</string>
    <string>-suspend</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>23</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>45</integer>
  </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is a good start, and suspends the session at 11.45pm. But it doesn't keep me out.

I also had the following as a second Daemon, but it didn't work out so well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<!-- SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0 -->
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>local.lock-session-bedtime2</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession</string>
    <string>-suspend</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <array>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>24</integer>
  </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This second Daemon kicks me out every minute for an hour starting at midnight. On paper it seemed like a decent solution, but it has problems. The first is that even once it's suspended the session, it continued to execute every minute, and so the lock screen goes black and then comes back. This seems to cause my laptop to run very hot, which is disconcerting. The second problem is that it seems to cue all 60 actions at once, and so if I sleep the computer, and open it back up the next day, it picks right back up where it left off.

I'm wondering if there are other options?

Something like the following would be perfect:

Between: 12am and 1am

If computer is logged in

Then suspend session.

Is it possible to write such a script as a launch agent? And if so, how?

Comment: Put it down and go do something else, bike ride or bake a cake.

Comment: You probably need to have launchd trigger a shell script which handles the nitty-gritty details. What kind of scripting languages do you know?

Comment: I've commented to several similar posts in the past that a technological solution to what is a psychological lack of willpower is outside the scope of this site. You'll find excellent sources on the web [here](https://buffer.com/resources/willpower-and-the-brain-why-its-so-hard-to-avoid-temptation/), [here](https://www.lifehack.org/articles/communication/15-ways-increase-our-willpower.html), and [here](https://positivepsychology.com/psychology-of-willpower/), which will help you with your technology 'addiction' and with other aspects of you life. No judging here - I struggle with it myself.